# How can I do ARIMA time series prediction for three constrained variables (x+y+z=1)?

Tags: math, statistics, time-series, prediction, arima

How can I PREDICT time-series for three variables that sum to 1? Say, x+y+z=1. I have historical data for x ,y, z , t. Based on historical data, I can create an ARIMA model for each variable individually, and make predictions for the future. How do I add the constraint?

If this were only one variable, applying an ARIMA is simple.

For the single variable x(t), I can get a fit ARIMA_x(p, d, q) and those three numbers parametrize the model.

Here, I could get three sets of fits independently. But that is not proper.

With three variables that always sum to 1, how do I get three sets of constrained fit parameters?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on math stack exchange- posting link here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322653/time-series-prediction-for-three-constrained-variables-xyz-1/3322665?noredirect=1#comment6836865_3322665